# ChordDiagram cutting off long labels

Tags: r, plot, graph, label, circlize

I wanted to plot 58 Variables that I saved in a dataframe data_relevant and their Connections to each other in a ChordDiagram using the circlize-package.

My Problem is the following: Some of my variable names that I must not Change have Long names and are therefore cut off by the plot, so that only one part of them is being shown in the actual plot. I tried to set different heights and lengths, but it either results in:

1) Labels that are plotted vertically are being partly cut off
2) Labels that are plotted horizontally are being partly cut off.

Is there any way of how I can get a full Picture with no Labels being cut off?

Here is the plotting code:

```
chordDiagram(data_relevant,
             grid.col = grid.col,
             annotationTrack = "grid",
             preAllocateTracks = list(track.height = max(strwidth(unlist(dimnames(data_relevant))))))

circos.track(track.index = 1, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
  circos.text(CELL_META$xcenter, CELL_META$ylim[1], CELL_META$sector.index, 
              facing = "clockwise", niceFacing = TRUE, adj = c(0, 0.5))
}, bg.border = NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using R to render the final graph, you can approach resolution by tweaking the arguments found in the documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/chorddiag/versions/0.1.3/topics/chorddiag.
For example, you can increase the margin, shrink the groupnameFontsize, etc.
Oh wait, it's now two years since you've posted this.  You've likely moved on by now!  I'm just seeing this because I'm just now trying again to use this flavor of the chord diagram.